# how to generate HTML FORM dynamically using any JSON object?

Tags: javascript, html, json, dynamic

I appreciate some help if anyone can tell me how we can generate HTML form dynamically based on  any JSON object using javascript?

Comment: This question is too broad to even answer. Definitely need more information than this

Comment: may i know what more info you require?

Comment: what will be the contents of the JSON? what goes into the body? which value from JSON goes to which tag? These are the questions to start with

Comment: the contents will be multiple objects containing data type,data name and data itself.

Comment: That just explains the contents of any objects but not how it should be mapped to HTML content

Comment: I am pretty sure that's not how stackoverflow works

Answer (score 1):

try this [seee](https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms)

You can use an existing library for that.

A simple one is:
[Angular Dynamic Forms](https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms)

More standard way is the [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) with this nice implementation [Angular Schema Form](http://schemaform.io/). See examples on how it works here [DEMO](http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>

 <body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
//create a form
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method',"post");
f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

//create input element
var i = document.createElement("input");
i.type = "text";
i.name = "user_name";
i.id = "user_name1";

//create a checkbox
var c = document.createElement("input");
c.type = "checkbox";
c.id = "checkbox1";
c.name = "check1";

//create a button
var s = document.createElement("input");
s.type = "submit";
s.value = "Submit";

// add all elements to the form
f.appendChild(i);
f.appendChild(c);
f.appendChild(s);

// add the form inside the body
$("body").append(f);   //using jQuery or
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f); //pure javascript

</script>
```

you can create as many elements as you want dynamically.

Comment: why a php file?